# django foreign key cannot be null

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am a beginner to django and trying to create a post request on django rest-framework.

I have a following model:

```
class ProjectScheme(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False,null=False)
    parent_scheme_id = models.ForeignKey(ProjectSchemeMaster, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    rule = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

And a serializer:

```
class SchemeDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectScheme
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'parent_scheme_id', 'rule')
        depth=1
```

And my view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
def create_project_scheme(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SchemeDetailSerializer(data=data)
        comp_logger.info('Call to create_project')

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:               
            return Response({'response':serializer.errors})
    return Response({})
```

With `post request body as`:

```
{
    "name": "django-rf"
}
```

This gives `serializer.is_valid()` to `true`, but in response I get

```
(1048, "Column 'parent_scheme_id_id' cannot be null")
```

I tried adding `parent_scheme_id = models.ForeignKey(ProjectSchemeMaster, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)` but that didn't make any difference.

How can I validate the request input so that it shows proper validation message like for `name` field?

Answer (score 1):

In your model, you set your ForeignKey field as a required field, Django by default consider a field `required=True` if not explicitely provide `null=True`. So if you want to create `ProjectScheme` instance without a ForeignKey referrence, then make sure you provide `null=True` to your ForeignKey field,

```
class ProjectScheme(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False,null=False)
    parent_scheme_id = models.ForeignKey(ProjectSchemeMaster, null=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    rule = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

in mention, `blank=True` works in `form` level validation.